# PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey with password

Tags: openssl, pem

I created a private key with:
 openssl genrsa -des3 -out private.pem 2048

During the key creation I was asked to enter and verify a password.

I used the following code to create an RSA from the key but got:
r=NULL.

Can you please help ?

Thank you,
Zvika

```
RSA *r;

fd = fopen ("private.pem","r");
r = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(fd, &r, NULL, "1234");
fclose (fd);
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code:

```
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers();
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
```

Found the solution here at:
[PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey function returns NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31377280/pem-read-rsaprivatekey-function-returns-null)

Now it works.

Thank you,
Zvika